# Ends a method before it to be finished with a tag system in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, tags, return, goto

I am working on a tags system not to allow to execute the next lines of the method if a tag function is found before the line, and the tag function has the same name that a given one. For example:

```
public void testLocateStore(String stopTag) {

    // Access to Web page
    webPageAccess();

    // Click on the "Login" hyperlink
    getScript().logOnSystem();

    // Complete user login data.
    getAccountScript().completeLoginData();

    Tags.stop(stopTag, "justAccess");

    // Access to my account
    getScript().accessToMyAccount();

    Tags.stop(stopTag, "stillLogged");

    // End session
    getScript().logout();

}//end testLocateStore
```

In the given case, if stopTag = "justAccess", 'getScript().accessToMyAccount();' and 'getScript().logout();' will not be executed, at the same way that if stopTag = "stillLogged", just 'getScript().logout();' will not be executed.

I know I can do it just using something like:

```
public void testLocateStore(String stopTag) {

    // Access to Web page
    webPageAccess();

    // Click on the "Login" hyperlink
    getScript().logOnSystem();

    // Complete user login data.
    getAccountScript().completeLoginData();

    if(stopTag.equals("justAccess")) {
        return;
    }

    // Access to my account
    getScript().accessToMyAccount();

    if(stopTag.equals("stillLogged")) {
        return;
    }

    // End session
    getScript().logout();

}//end testLocateStore
```

But I want a cleaner way, not to repeat the if statements, like the way I have shown you before, with a call method.

So, do you think it is possible to perfom, or it is just a fancy? Thank you.

Comment: I certainly think it's not a great idea: you delegate and hide a fundamental property of your method (that is, its code flow) to a submethod. It may be personal taste, but it doesn't seem cleaner to me.

Comment: About how to implement it, I think there's no way around doing it with a (preferably custom) Exception, wrapping the call of `testLocateStore` into a try-catch.